# Sending commands via serial connection

Tags: putty, serial-port, rs232, mobaxterm

I've got a [Sartorius GD-503](http://balance.balances.com/scales/559) electronic lab scale that I'm trying to work into a control setup. I've got both the [regular manual](http://www.scalenet.com/pdf/Sartorius_GD_GE.pdf) and the [data interface description manual](https://www.sartorius.com/fileadmin/fm-dam/DDM/Lab-Products-and-Services/Lab-Weighing/Gold-and-Carat/Manuals/MAN-GD_GE_Interface_Description-e.pdf).

So far I've got my laptop connected to the scale using a USB-to-DB9 cable to a DB9-to-DB25 cable to the back of the scale, matched up the connection parameter (7 bits, even parity, 1 stop bit, no flow control).

The scale is sending output to the laptop, which I'm reading using MobaXterm (or PuTTY). That part works fine. But how to *send* commands back to the scale stumps me. There is a brief section in the data interface manual on the structure of data input messages, but so far I'm not able to figure out how to 'send' anything...

P.S. Using Windows 10, so no HyperTerminal.

Comment: *"So far I've got my laptop connected ...,matched up the connection parameter (..., no flow control)"* -- So you have configured the PC side with no flow control, yet page 10 of *"Operating Instructions"* (your third link) states that there are only _two_ flow-control options: **Hardware** handshake (CTS/DTR) or **Software** handshake (XON, XOFF).  There is _no_ option for *"no flow control"*.  Seems like you have not properly configured the PC-side of the serial link (to match the scale's configuration).

Comment: Be sure that the *"DB9-to-DB25 cable"* that you're using conforms to the first cable diagram on page 12, which indicates a pair of shorted pins on each end.  This would mean a custom cable, and not one that you can buy off the shelf.  *"P.S. Using Windows 10, so no HyperTerminal"*  -- I would never recommend using HT except as a last resort.

Comment: @sawdust Valid points... I got the 'no flow control' setting from the supplier's (not manufacturer) page (http://www.lab-balances.com/sartorius/balances%2Bhyperterminal.html) and purchased the cabling that was supposed to be specific to that brand of scale (http://www.lab-balances.com/sartorius/sartorius-rs232.html) - I have not wrung out the cable but the fact it works at all seems to indicate it's wired correctly.

Comment: Also, I *have* tried configuring both the laptop and the scale for hardware & software control with no change, so I put it back to the default settings.

Comment: http://www.hilgraeve.com/hyperterminal/